# After added my Project reference unable to debug the class

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I created a dataaccess layer and it was builded sucessfully. I added this solution dll in my project but when i am trying to debug it was not hitting the break point. When i run my application it was showing the below warning message.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5fLp.png)

Comment: How did you add it to your project?  Normally I would expect the two projects to be in the same solution and use a Project Reference between them.  If you've compiled a Release DLL and copied that to a project, then Release DLLs typically don't have debugging symbols included.

Comment: it's not a release dll , it was a debug dll. I gone through the symbols and it was showing that Canot find or Open PDB file.

Comment: Read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x54fht41(v=vs.100).aspx) about the symbols and how to load them.

Comment: I trying to add the symbol but i am getting the message as "A matching symbol file was not found in this folder" but i am able to see the pdb file in that folder.